# Good indexing practices for performance in mysql databases

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, sqlalchemy

I'm about to deploy a web app which can end up with a quite big database and have some doubts which I would like to clear up before going live.

Will explain a bit my setup and most common querys:

1- I use sqlalchemy

2- I have many different tables referenced among them by their id (Integer unique field)

3- Some tables use a column with random 50chars unique string which I use client side to avoid exposing id to the clients. This column is indexed.

4- I also indexed some datetime columns which I use for querys which find rows in date ranges.

5- All relations are indexed because sometimes I query by that parameter.

6- Also have indexed some Bool columns which I query together with another index column.

So taking this in mind I ask:

In point 3: It's fine to query by this unique indexed 50chars string? It's not too long to work as index? Will work as fast now as with 50millions register?

Example query:

`customer=users.query.filter_by(secretString="ZT14V-_hD9qZrtwLj-rLPTioWQ1MJ4rhfqCUx8SvF0BrrCLtgvV_ZVXXV8_xXW").first()`

Then I use this user query to find his associated object:

`associatedObject=objects.query.filter_by(id=customer.associatedObject).first()`

So once I have this results I just get whatever I need from them:

`return({"username":user.Name,"AssociatedStuff":associatedObject.Name})`

About point 4:

Will this indexes in datetime columns do some work when comparing with < > operators?

About point 6:

It's ok to query something like:
`userFineshedTasks=tasks.query.filter(task.completed==True, task.userID==user.id).all()`
being completed and userID indexed columns and userID a reference to users id column.
"Note this query doesn't makes sense because I can get the user completed task from user.tasks.all() given they are referenced and filter the completed from there, but just like an example query..."

Basically asking for confirmation about if this is a correct way to query rows in a huge database given most of my querys will be for unique objects or if I'm doing something wrong.

Hope someone can let me know if this is a good practice or if I will have performance issues in the future.
Thanks in advance!

@Rick James:
Here I'm posting the create table sql code from the database export file:
Hope this is enough to get an idea, is an example of one of the tables, basically same ideas which applies to my questions.

`` CREATE TABLE `Bookings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CodigoAlojamiento` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Entrada` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Salida` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Habitaciones` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Precio` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `Agencia` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Extras` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `Confirmada` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NumeroOcupantes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Completada` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tarifa` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SafeURL` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailContacto` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `TelefonoContacto` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Titular` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Observaciones` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `IdentificadorReserva` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Facturada` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FacturarAClienteOAgencia` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pagada` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CheckOut` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PagaClienteOAgencia` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `NumeroFactura` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FechaFactura` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CheckIn` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EsPreCheckIn` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci; ``

here the indexes:

````
ALTER TABLE `Bookings`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `ix_Bookings_SafeURL` (`SafeURL`),
  ADD KEY `ix_Bookings_CodigoAlojamiento` (`CodigoAlojamiento`),
  ADD KEY `ix_Bookings_Tarifa` (`Tarifa`),
  ADD KEY `ix_BookingsE_CheckIn` (`CheckIn`),
  ADD KEY `ix_Bookings_CheckOut` (`CheckOut`),
  ADD KEY `ix_Bookings_Completada` (`Completada`),
  ADD KEY `ix_Bookings_Confirmada` (`Confirmada`),
  ADD KEY `ix_Bookings_Entrada` (`Entrada`),
  ADD KEY `ix_Bookings_EsPreCheckIn` (`EsPreCheckIn`),
  ADD KEY `ix_Bookings_Salida` (`Salida`);```

And here the references:

```ALTER TABLE `Bookings`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Bookings_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CodigoAlojamiento`) REFERENCES `Alojamientos` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `Bookings_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Tarifa`) REFERENCES `Tarifas` (`id`);```
````

Comment: It would be better to have specifics.  That is, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see the datatypes involved, plus sample `WHERE` clauses of what you would like to optimize.  With that, I can quickly say "Here are the indexes you need".

Comment: And please use SQL syntax, so we don't have to guess what Alchemy (etc) transforms things into.

Comment: Meanwhile, I can say that `<>` is rarely optimizable.  And "task.completed==True, task.userID==user.id" os probably best indexed with a "composite" `INDEX(userID, completed)` in either order.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: @RickJames, updated the questions, thanks for your reply!

Comment: Thanks for the updates.  Is `id` `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  If not, how are the values assigned?

Comment: yes, id is AUTO_INCREMENT, sorry, missed that portion of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 4- for querys which find rows in date ranges.

Usually there is something else in the `WHERE`, say

```
 WHERE x = 123
   AND Entrada BETWEEN ... AND ...
```

I that case this is optimal:  `INDEX(x, Entrada)`

```
`CheckOut` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
ADD KEY `ix_Bookings_CheckOut` (`CheckOut`),
```

- It is rarely useful to index a "flag".  However, a composite index (as above) may be useful.
- Why are most columns `NULLable`?  For "booleans", simply use 0 and 1 and `DEFAULT` to whichever one is appropriate.  Use `NULL` for "don't know", "optional", "not yet supplied", etc.
- 6- Also have indexed some Bool columns which I query together with another index column.

Then have a composite index.  And be sure to say `b=1` not `b<>0`, since `<>` does not optimize as well.

- It's fine to query by this unique indexed 50chars string? It's not too long to work as index? Will work as fast now as with 50millions register?

If the dataset becomes bigger than RAM, there is a performance problem with "random" indexes.  Your example should be fine.  (Personally, I think 50 chars is excessive.)  And such a 'hash' should probably be `CHARACTER SET ascii` and perhaps with `COLLATE ascii_bin` instead of a case-folding version.

- And "task.completed==True, task.userID==user.id" os probably best indexed with a "composite" `INDEX(userID, completed)` in either order.
- Yes, indexes in datetime columns do some work when comparing with <, <=, >, >= operators?  Strings can also be compared, though I do not see any likely columns for string comparisions other than with `=`.
- 50M rows is large, but not "huge".  Composite indexes are often important for large tables.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your overview :) Will think about your suggestions, good to know the only limitation for speed will be RAM, if my database grows so much then it should be producing enough money to afford increase RAM. BTW, what does the COLLATE ascii_bin and CHARACTER SET ascii ? it's just the encoding right? I feel like I miss a bit low level knowledge base here... All this low level stuff is handled by default by sqlalchemy in my case and didn't paid much attention, but would be good to know

Comment: @lopalcar - You example hash looks like upper and lowercase ascii characters, no accents, no Chinese, etc. `_bin` distinguishes between `a` and `A`, which you probably need.